# Android Studio Gradle Task Error

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

I am new to android studio.when i am creating a new project it shows errors

```
Cause:Finish can only be called once.
Error:committed = 37380096 should be < max = 33554432
```

I took the help of Google and tried `Invalidate Caches/Restart,Clean Project and Rebuild` as per the suggestions but still same errors are coming and my `Run` button is also disabled....I am using Android Studio 2.3.3 and jdk 1.8 in Windows 8 32-bit.

Please help.

Comment: is not a gradle error, you are just calling the finish(); method more than one time, post your code and your log and I'll answer

Comment: @Brandon Till now i have not written any code...i just have created a simple project during Android Studio startup....During Gradle sync `Error:committed = 37380096 should be < max = 33554432` error is coming...

Comment: Post the code of the gradle and the complete info in the logcat (in one of the bottom tabs)